# Como sumar total de columnas, y que se muestre el total aunque uno o varios inputs este "vacio", Javascript

Tags: javascript

Bien, tengo una tabla sencilla para que se pueda entender rápido lo que necesito porque la tabla original es demasiado grande, entonces hice este ejemplo rapido:

```js
 function calcular_c(){
        const tiempo1 = parseInt(document.getElementById('tiempo1').value);
        const costo1 = parseInt(document.getElementById('costo1').value);
       
        const tiempo2 = parseInt(document.getElementById('tiempo2').value);
        const costo2 = parseInt(document.getElementById('costo2').value);

        const tiempo3 = parseInt(document.getElementById('tiempo3').value);
        const costo3 = parseInt(document.getElementById('costo3').value);

        const total1 = tiempo1 * costo1 ; 
        const total2 = tiempo2 * costo2 ; 
        const total3 = tiempo3 * costo3 ; 

        document.getElementById('total1').value = total1;
        document.getElementById('total2').value = total2;
        document.getElementById('total3').value = total3;
        
        const suma_horas = tiempo1 + tiempo2 + tiempo3;
        const suma_total = total1+  total2 + total3 ;

        document.getElementById('total_tiempo').value = suma_horas;
        document.getElementById('total_total').value = suma_total;
    
    }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="container">
    <table class="table table-hover table-sm">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>tiempo</th>
                <th>costo</th>
                <th>total</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="number" class="form-control" id="tiempo1" value="" onkeyup="calcular_c();"></td>
                <td><input type="number" class="form-control" id="costo1" value="" onkeyup="calcular_c();"></td>
                <td><input type="number" class="form-control" id="total1" value="" onkeyup="calcular_c();"></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="number" class="form-control" id="tiempo2" value="" onkeyup="calcular_c();"></td>
                <td><input type="number" class="form-control" id="costo2" value="" onkeyup="calcular_c();"></td>
                <td><input type="number" class="form-control" id="total2" value="" onkeyup="calcular_c();"></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="number" class="form-control" id="tiempo3" value="" onkeyup="calcular_c();"></td>
                <td><input type="number" class="form-control" id="costo3" value="" onkeyup="calcular_c();"></td>
                <td><input type="number" class="form-control" id="total3" value="" onkeyup="calcular_c();"></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
        <tfoot>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <th>total tiempo</th>
                    <th></th>
                    <th>total suma</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th><input type="number" class="form-control" id="total_tiempo" value="" onkeyup="calcular_c();"></th>
                    <th></th>
                    <th><input type="number" class="form-control" id="total_total" value="" onkeyup="calcular_c();"></th>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </tfoot>
    </table>
</div>
```

> Lo que necesito es que cuando ingrese una cantidad se muestre en el total, sin importar si aun faltan campos por llenar de forma vertical (columnas)

Ejemplo lo que quiero conseguir:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

> entones como se ve en la imagen, quisiera que llenando solo 1 o 2 `inputs` el total de esa columna se vaya mostrando.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basta con comprobar si ha sido posible realizar el *parseado* del valor como número. Te recomendaría utilizar una función auxiliar:

```
function ensureNumber( val, def ) {
  var def = def || 0;
  var parsed = parseInt( val );

  return isNaN( parsed ) ? def : parsed;
}
```

Y cambiar tu código a

```
const tiempo1 = ensureNumber( document.getElementById( 'tiempo1' ).value );
...
```

Por defecto, devuelve `0` si el valor no es un número. Si necesitas otro valor (por ejemplo, para multiplicar), basta con pasarlo como 2º argumento:

```
const costo1 = ensureNumber( document.getElementById( 'tiempo1' ).value, 1 );
```

Comment: si me funciona cumple lo que necesito, tenia en mente hacer algo similar a lo que me compartes, pero de otra forma, iba a ser muy extenso y tampoco sabia si funcionaria, lo que me respondiste esta preciso. GRACIAS.